# Transforming data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transform a data frame in an efficient way using the following logic:

For each column of the data frame, I identify the unique occurrences that appear in that particular column. Say that for column i there are n_i unique such occurrences. Then to each of these occurrences I assign the unique list with n_i components such that that list has zeros everywhere except one position corresponding to the chosen unique occurrence. By doing this for every column, I will have uniquely identified each element in the data frame by a list of lists. An example might come in much more handy in order to explain what I want.

Take the following data frame:

```
data = { 'name': ['Alarm1','Alarm2','Alarm2','Alarm3','Alarm4'],
    'severity':[1,2,3,4,4],
    'domain':['RAN','TRX','RAN','RAN','TRX']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data, index = [1,2,3,4,5])
```

Then I would like to transform this data frame in an numpy array looking like the output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1]]
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1]]
```

My code for the above transformation is the following:

```
l0=[((df.name.unique()==df.iloc[0][0])*1).tolist(),((df.severity.unique()==df.iloc[0][1])*1).tolist()]
l0.append(((df.domain.unique()==df.iloc[0][2])*1).tolist())
l1=[((df.name.unique()==df.iloc[1][0])*1).tolist(),((df.severity.unique()==df.iloc[1][1])*1).tolist()]
l1.append(((df.domain.unique()==df.iloc[1][2])*1).tolist())
l2=[((df.name.unique()==df.iloc[2][0])*1).tolist(),((df.severity.unique()==df.iloc[2][1])*1).tolist()]
l2.append(((df.domain.unique()==df.iloc[2][2])*1).tolist())
l3=[((df.name.unique()==df.iloc[3][0])*1).tolist(),((df.severity.unique()==df.iloc[3][1])*1).tolist()]
l3.append(((df.domain.unique()==df.iloc[3][2])*1).tolist())
l4=[((df.name.unique()==df.iloc[4][0])*1).tolist(),((df.severity.unique()==df.iloc[4][1])*1).tolist()]
l4.append(((df.domain.unique()==df.iloc[4][2])*1).tolist())
```

After this I just print all of the lists l0,..,l4 in order to get the output. Of course this is highly inefficient as I construct each of these lists by hand. I would like to iterate in order to construct all of them at once and also iterate for the column.unique part for each column in the data frame for each of the lists.

I would greatly appreciate if someone could provide some help or advice. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think need [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) working with strings values, so first is used [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
print (df1)
   name_Alarm1  name_Alarm2  name_Alarm3  name_Alarm4  severity_1  severity_2  \
1            1            0            0            0           1           0   
2            0            1            0            0           0           1   
3            0            1            0            0           0           0   
4            0            0            1            0           0           0   
5            0            0            0            1           0           0   

   severity_3  severity_4  domain_RAN  domain_TRX  
1           0           0           1           0  
2           0           0           0           1  
3           1           0           1           0  
4           0           1           1           0  
5           0           1           0           1
```

Then if need lists use `groupby` by first value before `_` to list of tuples:

```
L = list(zip(*[x.values.tolist() for _, x in df1.groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[0], axis=1)]))
print (L)

[([1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0]), 
 ([0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0]), 
 ([1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]), 
 ([1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]), 
 ([0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1])]
```

Or create `MultiIndex` in columns with [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
print (df1)
    name                      severity          domain    
  Alarm1 Alarm2 Alarm3 Alarm4        1  2  3  4    RAN TRX
1      1      0      0      0        1  0  0  0      1   0
2      0      1      0      0        0  1  0  0      0   1
3      0      1      0      0        0  0  1  0      1   0
4      0      0      1      0        0  0  0  1      1   0
5      0      0      0      1        0  0  0  1      0   1
   Alarm1  Alarm2  Alarm3  Alarm4
1       1       0       0       0
2       0       1       0       0
3       0       1       0       0
4       0       0       1       0
5       0       0       0       1
```

So is possible select `DataFrame` by first level:

```
print (df1['name'])
   Alarm1  Alarm2  Alarm3  Alarm4
1       1       0       0       0
2       0       1       0       0
3       0       1       0       0
4       0       0       1       0
5       0       0       0       1

print (df1['domain'])
   RAN  TRX
1    1    0
2    0    1
3    1    0
4    1    0
5    0    1
```

And if necessary convert to `numpy array`:

```
print (df1['name'].values)
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]

print (df1['domain'].values)
[[1 0]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need `pd.get_dummies`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'name': ['Alarm1','Alarm2','Alarm2','Alarm3','Alarm4'],
    'severity': [1,2,3,4,4],
    'domain': ['RAN','TRX','RAN','RAN','TRX']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[1,2,3,4,5])
df = df.astype(str)

df2 = pd.get_dummies(df)

out = list(zip(*[df2[[x for x in df2.columns if x.startswith(key)]].values.tolist() for key in data.keys()]))
print(out)

# Output
# [([1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0]), 
#  ([0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1]), 
#  ([0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0]), 
#  ([0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0]), 
#  ([0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1])]
```